# What algorithm can find a gradient increase using the maximum value of small circles on a two dimensional plot?

Tags: algorithms, gradient

I'm looking to make research on an algorithm that finds the maximum increase (gradient) on a 2D-landscape using the maximum values found on circles.

The algorithm looks at the values on each circle to find the maximum value on it. Then it uses this maximum as the center of the next circle to do the same… in short:

1. Start at an initial point on the plot
2. draw a circle with radius *r* centred on the point
3. find the maximum value on the circle
4. use the maximum value of the circle as the center of a new circle with same radius *r*
5. repeat step 3 and 4 until you reach a peak (i.e., the maximum value on a circle don't continue to growth).

The track left behind by the maximum value of each circle gives an indication of the maximum increase using the circle method.

I'm pretty sure this algorithm was already describe, but can't find its name. What is it called?

[image]

Comment: linesearch [https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Line_search_methods] is common. Maybe you can explain how many evaluations are performed in your circle search, as it's not clear in what way it's 'optimal'

Comment: maybe you meant trust region. https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Trust-region_methods

Comment: The 'precision' of the method, meaning how many circles will be evaluated depends on the radius of each circle. The smaller the radius, the more circles, but also, the more precise the path becomes. The 'way for optimality' depends only on finding the maximum value on the circonférence of the circle evaluated at a specific iteration. I've heard of the Runge-Kutta and Milne methods, but not sure if it is the same thing as I've never seen such 'maximum-circle' method explained this way.

Comment: By optimality I meant - why do you think your 'circle search' is better than line search.  What you are suggesting seems not efficient. I understand you assume you have the gradient, then why not follow steepest descent and use linesearch to identify optimal step along gradient. (why evaluate at multiple points on circumference if you have gradient telling you already which direction to follow).

Comment: Oh! I see, because I know very little about this. I'm doing this in `R` and don't know how to implement these kind of algorithm from the image above (I can see this is derivative stuff). So I generated my own gradient function that can do this... with circles. I'm not claiming that this circle method is superior. I'm wondering if this is already known (the circle method, even though it might be inefficient). There might be a way to use the line search for what I'm doing now. I have no idea on how to implement this in the code I have!

Comment: Imagine I have a matrix of values only (like a raster). I'm using the circles to reach the maximum value. Simple and intuitive (although not efficient). I'm not sure I understand the comment `you assume you have the gradient`. I don't, at least from the 'raster' type data I have. I randomly start on a similar landscape and want to find the steepest (path) increase to a maximum. I don't have a system of equations or any 'gradient' *per se*. Only numbers in a matrix for which there is a maximum I want to reach (not necessarily in a straight line). Make sense? Is it the case of a line search?

Comment: If you don't have gradient information, then nelder mead might be a useful and efficient way. see https://www.benfrederickson.com/numerical-optimization/ which has inetractive demo in 2d

Comment: Note also that I *do not* have a 'function' like `f(x1, x2) = 100 * (x2 - x1 * x1)^2 + (1 - x1)^2`. Only a matrix of numbers for which I want to find the path to the maximum. The `Nelder-Mead` algorithms that I saw in R requires a function to run the optimization. This is why I also thought that the circle method was the most pragmatic (with my limited knowledge on the subject).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149947/discussion-between-seanv507-and-m-beausoleil).